# FoxPro app calling SQL Server stored procedure returning an OUTPUT parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have a Fox Pro Application in which I'm having trouble getting the results of the OUTPUT parameter

I am trying to call it like this

```
 cSQL = "Exec CustomerKeyChecker @ldccode = " + ProgramValidation.LdcCode + " , @result=0" 

Thisform.displaycnk = thisform.oSql.SQLExec(cSql)
```

Problem is `This.displaycnk` is always `True` ...

I can call my stored procedure from SSMS like this

```
DECLARE @return_value int, @result int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[CustomerKeyChecker]
                            @ldccode = N'psnh',
                            @result = @result OUTPUT

SELECT @result as N'@result'
SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Results are either a 0 or 1

Stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomerKeyChecker]
    @ldccode VARCHAR(12),
    @result INT OUTPUT
 .... 
   RETURN @result
```

So with Fox Pro, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two things. First is you didn't specify your result parameter as OUTPUT when you call your procedure. But the biggest issue is that you need to learn about parameterized queries. Building up a string and executing it is vulnerable to sql injection....just don't do it. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: It is an internal fox pro that is going to go away within a year,  I just have not seen any code with FoxPro using OUTPUT ...

Comment: Regardless of the life span it is easy to use parameterized queries. It should become the defacto way of writing code. And of course since you did not add this as a parameter you can't get the value because the value would go to the parameter.

Comment: Where do I specify the OUTPUT?

Answer (score 1):

> Your "return_value" is not really a return value but a select result.
>   A real return value would be returned by a return statement and for an
>   SP call is always an integer.

Making that note aside, if you had really a return value, then with ODBC it would look like:

```
cSQL = "{?@m.returnvalue = CALL CustomerKeyChecker(?ProgramValidation.LdcCode, ?@m.result)}" 
LOCAL returnvalue,result, lnConnectionHandle
returnvalue = 0
result = 0

lnConnectionHandle = SQLSTRINGCONNECT( ... )
SQLEXEC(m.lnConnectionHandle, m.cSQL)
SQLDISCONNECT(0)
? m.returnvalue, m.result
```

Since in your case it is not a return value but a select result, you can add the 3rd parameter as a result cursor and check its first column:

```
SQLEXEC(m.lnConnectionHandle, m.cSQL, 'crsRet')
select crsRet
browse
```

And these are samples to do check output parameters and return value using OLEDB (from one of my posts on UT):

Here is a series of ways to do it.
First for the below sample this is stored procedure (create in Northwind database):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_test 
 @country varchar(10), @customers int output AS 
 select * from customers where country = @country
 set @customers = @@rowcount
 if ( @customers > 10 )
    return 33
 else
    return 22
```

(to get the return value recordset needs to be closed)

```
#DEFINE adInteger   3
#DEFINE adCurrency  6
#DEFINE adDate      7
#DEFINE adBoolean   11
#DEFINE adChar      129
#DEFINE adNumeric   131
#DEFINE adVarChar   200
#DEFINE adDBTimeStamp   135
#DEFINE adParamInput    1
#DEFINE adParamOutput   2
#define adParamReturnValue 4
#DEFINE adCmdStoredProc 4

clear
Local cn As ADODB.Connection,;
  cmd As ADODB.Command,;
  rs As ADODB.Recordset
cn  = CreateObject('ADODB.Connection')
cmd = CreateObject('ADODB.Command')
rs  = CreateObject('ADODB.Recordset')

cn.ConnectionString = "Provider = SQLOLEDB;"+;
 "Server=servername;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes"
cn.Open

cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

* Way 1
cmd.CommandText = "usp_test"
cmd.CommandType = 4 && adCmdStoredProc

* Set up parameters
retParm = cmd.CreateParameter("Return", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
inParm = cmd.CreateParameter("Input", adVarChar, adParamInput,10)
outParm = cmd.CreateParameter("Output", adInteger, adParamOutput)

cmd.Parameters.Append(retParm)
cmd.Parameters.Append(inParm)
cmd.Parameters.Append(outParm)

lcCountry = Trim(InputBox("Enter country:"))
inParm.Value = m.lcCountry

* Way 2
*!* cmd.CommandText = "usp_test"
*!* cmd.CommandType = 4 && adCmdStoredProc

*!* * Set up parameters asking backend
*!* cmd.Parameters.Refresh
*!*   
*!* lcCountry = Trim(InputBox("Enter country:"))
*!* cmd.Parameters("@country").Value = m.lcCountry

* Way 3
*!* cmd.CommandText = "{? = Call usp_Test(?,?)}"
*!* cmd.CommandType = 1 && text

*!* * Set up parameters
*!* retParm = cmd.CreateParameter("Return", adInteger, adParamReturnValue)
*!* inParm  = cmd.CreateParameter("Input", adVarChar, adParamInput,10)
*!* outParm = cmd.CreateParameter("Output", adInteger, adParamOutput)

*!* cmd.Parameters.Append(retParm)
*!* cmd.Parameters.Append(inParm)
*!* cmd.Parameters.Append(outParm)
*!*   
*!* lcCountry = Trim(InputBox("Enter country:"))
*!* inParm.Value = m.lcCountry

* Execute command
rs = cmd.Execute
* Show result
DO While !rs.EOF
    ? rs.Fields(0).Value
    rs.MoveNext
enddo

* Need to close recordset before getting return 
* and output parameters.
rs.Close

* check return values - 1 output and 1 return code
* For Way 1 and Way 3
? "Return code: ", Cmd.Parameters("Return").Value && or Parameters(0)
? "Total rows: ", Cmd.Parameters("OutPut").Value && or Parameters(2)

* For Way 2
*!* ? "Return code: ", Cmd.Parameters(0).Value && or Parameters(0)
*!* ? "Total rows: ", Cmd.Parameters("@customers").Value && or Parameters(2)

cn.Close
```

Please note that return value is always the first parameter -Parameters(0)-.
In way 1 and 3 parameters append order exactly matches SPs definition (positional) - Parameters(0)=return value, Parameters(1) = first parameter, Parameters(2) = second parameter and so on. Name of the parameters has no importance.
In way 2 instead of appending parameters we 'ask' it to the stored procedure (note that this would cause a trip to server) and use named parameters (names match to that of SP parameter names) OR you might use ordinals - Parameters(0),Parameters(1)...

Comment: I don't understand  `?@m.returnvalue `

Comment: ?  and @   and m  --  what are all those

Comment: ? is the parameter placeholder (not specific to VFP). @ is by reference as in the documentation.

Comment: m is of course memory variable prefix. Those are all basic 101 syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

Adding another sample (as another message to prevent crowd in previous):

```
TEXT TO mySampleSP noshow
create procedure #myCustomerSummary 
  @customerId varchar(10), @firstDate datetime output, @lastDate datetime output, @ordercount integer output
as
  set nocount on
  if exists (select * from customers where customerID = @customerID)
        begin 
            select 
                @firstDate = min(orderdate), 
                @lastDate = max(orderdate), 
                @ordercount = count(orderid)
            from orders
            where customerid = @customerId
            return 1
        end
  else
    return 0
ENDTEXT

handle = SQLSTRINGCONNECT("Driver={SQL native client};"+;
 "server=.\sqlexpress;database=Northwind;trusted_connection=yes")

SQLEXEC(m.handle,m.mySampleSP)

lcSQL  = "{?@m.return = Call #MyCustomerSummary(?m.customer,?@m.first,?@m.last,?@m.orders)}"

return = 0
customer = 'BONAP'
first = DATETIME()
last = DATETIME()
orders = 0

IF SQLEXEC(handle,m.lcSQL) < 0
    AERROR(aWHy)
    DISPLAY MEMORY LIKE aWhy
ELSE
    ? 'Success'
    ? m.return, m.first, m.last, m.orders
ENDIF
SQLDISCONNECT(0)
```